# Tk_GetPixmap: Error from DIBSection - The parameter is incorrect

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a Rock Paper Scissors game. When I run the application, I get a tkinter messagebox titled 'Tk_GetPixmap: Error from DIBSection' and says 'The parameter is incorrect'. Here's the image:

[image: Error]

But the thing is I haven't used DIBSection or Tk_GetPixmap anywhere in my code. Could someone please explain why this error may come without usage?

I didn't get a traceback which makes it hard for me myself to debug and I dont know anything about DIBSection. I tried checking for other questions on StackOverflow but all of them used DIBSection in the code. I think I cannot create a minimal reproducible example for this so I have not pasted the code. If there is a need to do so, please ask. Thanks in advance for anyone who helps!

EDIT: Here's a small slice of code likely causing the error:

```py
def start_round(self):
    def rd_animate():
        #--::Animation::--#
        self.remove_wdgs()
        self.PF_ani_lbl["text"] = "ROUND {}".format(self.round_no)
        self.after(1000, self.place_wdgs)

    print("start_round")
    
    self.round = {}

    #--::Animation::--#
    rd_animate()
```

Comment: Please include the part where you generate your images.

Comment: I have added the image into the question

Comment: Do you use/generate images in your code?

Comment: @Thingamabobs, It creates a GUI in which I can play with the computer. I enter my match settings (Like target, etc.) and create the match and then it shows me the above error.

Comment: I use images for buttons. But I use PIL's `ImageTk.PhotoImage` to import the images into the code.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249027/discussion-between-pycoder-and-thingamabobs).

Comment: @Thingamabobs, I have posted the slice of code formatted in the question. Hope you can solve it now. Even if you can't, thanks for spending so much time trying to debug the error for me.

Comment: look into chat.

Comment: @Thingamabobs, Here is the code: https://github.com/PrathamPy/RPSGame